# Windows.h дает ошибку при подключении

Tags: c++, sfml

нет ошибки:

```
#include "pch.h"
//#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
int main()
{

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Lesson");
    return 0;
}
```

есть ошибка:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
int main()
{

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Lesson");
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка C2589 (: недопустимая лексема справа от "::" q2222 c:\libs\sfml-2.5.1\x86\include\sfml\graphics\rect.inl

Почему то windows.h и sfml не хотят в паре работать.Хотя по отдельности пашут.Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типичный пример конфликта имен, вызванный макросами `min` и `max` из `<windows.h>`.

Либо включайте `<windows.h>` после остальных заголовков, либо (лучше) глобально определите макро `NOMINMAX` в настройках проекта, либо сделайте

```
#undef min
#undef max
```

сразу после включения `<windows.h>`.